# Limit connections to different destinations in RxJava/Micronaut project

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming, micronaut

I have a project that reads data from many different providers; some via SOAP, some via HTTP, etc. Some of these providers also have a restriction on the number of concurrent connections to them. For example, provider A may allow unlimited connections, provider B may only allow 2, and provider C may allow 5.

I'm decent with Micronaut, but I'm unaware of anything built into it that would allow me to limit connections to specific URLs as necessary. So, my first thought is to create a per-provider thread limit (perhaps using RxJava's scheduler system? I believe you can create custom ones using Java's Executor class) and let that do the work of queuing for me. I think I could also go the more manual route of creating a ConcurrentMap and storing the number of active connections in that, but that seems messier and more error-prone.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Limiting thread numbers is suitable only if the network connections are made by threads, that is, synchronously. But Micronaut also can make asynchronous connections, and then limiting the number of threads won't work. Better do limiting the number of connections directly. Create an intermediate proxy object with has the same interface as Micronaut and passes all incoming requests to the real Micronaut. It also has a parameter - limit, and when a request is passed, decrements the limit. when the limit becomes 0, the proxy object stops passing requests, keeping them in an input queue. As soon as a request is finished, it signals the proxy object and it passes one request from the input queue, if any, or just increments the limit.

The simplest implementation of the proxy is a thread with BlockingQueue for input requests and Semaphore for limit. But if there are many providers and creating a thread for each provider is expensive, the proxy can be implemented as an asynchronous object.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, it's definitely helpful! I realized based on your feedback that I actually need to account for multiple Micronaut instances also, so I'm thinking I'll need to do a distributed semaphore or something similar... I'll likely try out redis for this, since we already use it for some things. Does that make sense? Or am I missing anything?

Comment: @patrickj I am afraid using Redis or other database for this is an overkill. Simple object with synchronized access consisting of  a queue and a counter would do the job.